# Sharing ground between two fully bridge rectified AC signals

Tags: ac, ground, rectifier, bridge-rectifier, linear-regulator

I am designing a device which has two AC input signals. The Input signals are as follows.

```
A - AC Signal A
B - AC Signal B
Com - Shared Neutral for above inputs
```

Voltages of these signals could be anywhere between 12V-35V(rms,50Hz). These signals are used as both power and control signals for the device. The functionality of the circuit is like following.

```
AC signal applied between A and Com - Do Task X
AC signal applied between B and Com - Do Task Y
AC signal applied between both A,Com and B,Com - Do Task Y (Same as above)
```

Since it's hard to work with AC unregulated signals I wish to convert them to DC signals(and also DC power for the circuit will be drawn from the signals) and probably implement the rest of the circuit with logic gates or transistors. For this reason I need them to be rectified and share a common ground. I have designed following circuit with two bridge rectifiers and common ground, but it's no good. When AC is applied to Com and B, on the negative half cycle current conducts through the rectifier of signal A. I would be extremely grateful if someone could guide me for a better implementation.

I have also tried to create some other designs but couldn't make it to functional one.

Edit: I prefer a design without a center tap transformer

[image: Current circuit design]

Edit:

I have modified the design with the suggestions from @Kyle B and now I have a +Vcc GND -Vcc type power supply which is absolutely fine for my design.

Edit:
With the excitement of voltage outputs I forgot to measure currents. When I measured them later it turned out to be order of hundreds which suggested an open circuit. Later I found out there is indeed and open circuit through diodes in this circuit. So this design not longer valid and I'm back to any new suggestions again :-(

[image: new schematic design]

[image: output waveform]

Comment: A, B and Com are connected to a center tap transformer ... one bridge rectifier between A and B ... Com connected to ground ... the two outputs of the bridge rectifier are the **+** and **-** .....

Comment: @jsotola thanks for the response. That is a design I have considered. But I prefer an implementation without a transformer (considering cost and size). Is there any other method?

Comment: Is it possible to change the phase of one of your input AC signals???  If you can flip one 180 degrees, you won't have this problem.

Comment: And... If you're simulating this, are your phases correct to "reality"???

Comment: @KyleB hi, The signals are meant to be supplied from a same source with switches so I don't think there could be much phase difference. I'm not sure if putting a phase difference will work since it's not essential to be same sources are connected at once?

Comment: Actually....   I think if you flip pins 2 & 4 on one of your rectifiers, it'll work....

Comment: @KyleB That's a briliant idea I think! Thank you! I think I could add a capacitor in series for once source to make 180 phase. I'll try with some simulation

Comment: It might be pins 1 & 3 you need to flip... Have to think it through.   Simulating will tell you immediately....

Comment: Sure, I'll post the results

Comment: @KyleB Thank you very much! It worked! I have updated the question with new design and results. If you wish to post the solution as an answer I'm more than happy to accept :-)

Comment: @Anuradha did you mean to place R4 where it is??  All the current going to the top bridge has to go through R4. You have R3 placed across the bridge... It's different.

Comment: @Kyle B I think I won't need R4. I removed it and the design worked fine.

Comment: @Anuradha THe reason R4 would have been a problem is you are looking at simulation results for only voltage. You have to consider the load. Soon as you started drawing much current, you would lose voltage over that resistor (by ohms law E=IR). How big is your load??? Note those regulators have to sink power. If you are dropping 35V -> 5V, that's 30V across the regulator. For example, with 100mA load, that's 30*0.1=3W.. Quite alot really. Also, the LM7805 won't like 35V applied, that's it's max rating. Suggest pick a different regulator with higher input voltage specs

Comment: @KyleB I'm terribly sorry I have made a critical mistake here. With the excitement of  voltage output I forgot to measure the currents. When I later measured it it turned out to be in order of hundreds which suggests and open circuit through diodes and later I found out there is indeed an open circuit. Therefore I'm sorry I cannot accept this design as an answer and I'm open for any new suggestions again.

Comment: Maybe you should delete this question and start over, it's starting to get messy.  You said you removed R4... Can you post your "corrected" circuit?  And curious, why do you need two different AC sources, your simulation has only one.  You also said you were going to select between the AC sources with a switch...  Are there really two unique AC sources here?  If not, couldn't you use a single bridge rectifier in the traditional way and switch between two DC regulators??

Comment: @KyleB Yes I think it's getting too messy. I'll delete the question and post corrected schematics with more information thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Flip the bridge rectifier around

TY for the points   ;)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me the simplest method would be to use half wave rectifiers (diodes)  and use a common ground for inputs and outputs.   That way you can have both outputs moving in the same polarity and completely independent.